# sinatra app on puma server set to port 80 via non-bootstraped executable

Tags: ruby, sinatra, puma

I'm trying to bind my app to port 80, it binds to '0.0.0.0' fine but using

```
set :port,80
```

doesn't change port its set to.

I can't use anything that requires me to externally set the port because I'm starting my app from inside an executable like this:

```
    if options[:daemonize]
        use Rack::Deflater
        pid = fork {Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App}
        File.open(options[:pid], 'w') {|f| f.write(pid)}
        Process.detach(pid)
    else
        use Rack::Deflater
        Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App
    end
```

I've looked but beyond using `set` I can't find how else to set the port.
I'm using chef to provision the application and start it which should have super user access.

P.s. Just in case it wasn't obvious, when I say non-bootstraped I mean by not doing a system command that does runs rackup or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging away through both rack and puma source code I was able to get an answer.

You just pass it in when you use `.run` like this:

```
Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App, {:Port => 80}
```

so my code ends up like this:

```
    server_config = {
        :Host => options[:host],
        :Port => options[:port],
        :Threads => "0:#{options[:threads]}",
        :Verbose => options[:verbose],
        :environment => options[:environment]
    }
    if options[:daemonize]
        use Rack::Deflater
        pid = fork {Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App,server_config}
        File.open(options[:pid], 'w') {|f| f.write(pid)}
        Process.detach(pid)
    else
        use Rack::Deflater
        Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App
    end
```

which in hind-site is kind of obvious.

Also I'd like to state that this line I found in the rack handler code to retrieve the server object is VERY clever:

```
klass.split("::").inject(Object) { |o, x| o.const_get(x) }
```